# Android CMake: how to check if cppFlags and arguments are taken into account at compile time?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Android/NDK/JNI/Java/C++ project.

I have a Gradle file that looks like this:

```
....
 cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
            }
....
```

My question is: how to check that these flags and arguments are well taken into account when my Android project is compiled ?

Thanks

Comment: It is taken. but if you want to see all flags including these ones, just check generated make files in cmake cache folder. Mine is much more complex and options are taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a big cmake file with parts like this:

```
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                cFlags "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS", "-fno-integrated-as", "-fvisibility=hidden"
                cppFlags "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-fno-integrated-as", "-fvisibility=hidden"
            }

//...
        flavorDimensions "mode"

        productFlavors {
            normal {
                dimension "mode"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    cmake {
                        cFlags "-DNORMAL"
                        cppFlags "-DNORMAL"
                    }
                }
            }
            demo {
                dimension "mode"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    cmake {
                        cFlags "-DDEMO"
                        cppFlags "-DDEMO"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and all options are taken into account. But you can check cmake cache files if you want. Build file is named `build.ninja`, and you can find it in your project variant folder inside `.cxx` folder.

In general, `arguments` are arguments that is passed to cmake, but `cppFlags` are flags that are passed to compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Where do you find these cache files?

Comment: @Regis_AG in newer versions of android studio, cache is in `.cxx` folder. go inside till you reach your variant folder. then look for `build.ninja` file. You can see flag inside it because android uses ninja build system by default.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it seems that I see my flags there. By the way, how do I know if I should put a flag in 'cppFlags' or 'arguments'?

Comment: @Regis_AG `arguments` are cmake arguments. `cppflags` are flags that you want to pass to compiler, e.g. clang. in addition, some compile flags can be set via cmake itself too.

Comment: Thanks. For example, should I set flags like "-O2" or "-DNDEBUG" in 'cppFlags' or 'arguments'?

Comment: @Regis_AG I'm not sure sure if it is necessary to define those flags. Because when your build type changes, some flags will automatically changed by cmake itself, So I think those flags should be defined when you sync your project for release build. But in general, such flags will go to `cppflags`. But as I mentioned, try building release version first and You will probably see those flags. Remember both android studio/gradle and cmake are trying to simplify process, so if you poke too much, you may get a worse result.

Comment: @Regis_AG Your're welcome. Just mark it as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Last question @Afshin as you seem to be a great expert on these topics. How can I do to be sure that Android Studio will not compile/run my project with different parameters in debug and release modes ? Indeed I can see that the speed of my project is very different in release and debug modes (much faster in release mode). I would like to have the same performance in debug mode as in release mode. How to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @Regis_AG You will need debug mode for debugging your code and your product will eb released in release mode with higher speed, so I don't think it is a problem and it should be like this. But you need to have release dll for both debug and release, I think it may be possible by depending your main project to release version of C++ library. But my advice, don't do it. You will need to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks ! Ok, so I understand that release mode has some optimizations that make the code faster but make debugging impossible. So Indeed, both modes should be used for what they are designed. I never realized that...  Perhaps, there is less speed difference between these two modes when the code is 100% java (without NDK/C++)? Thanks a lot for these great explanations.